# Compare identical key values in a NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a JSON result that consist in NSmutableArray with Dictionarys, and I want to know how iterate and compare identical key values (`id_sucursal` in my case) and to save it in Array to create cluster annotation. Below is the JSON result:

```
    {
    ancla = 1;
    categoria = 12;
    descripcion = "Gur\U00fa Ofertas te trae un 15% de descuento* en todos los platos o un postre* de cortes\U00eda en el Centro Cultural Mediterr\U00e1neo La Gloria";
    descuento = 16;
    "id_cupon" = 540;
    "id_sucursal" = 45;
    lat = "4.63323";
    lon = "-74.144474";
    premium = "<null>";
    rutaimagen = "ruta/imagen/14";
    tipooferta = "% Descuento";
    titulo = "Decoraciones del hogar Home Center";
    zona = 2;
},
    {
    ancla = "<null>";
    categoria = 4;
    descripcion = "$50.000 en vez de $120.000 por noche romantica para dos personas. Incluye cena romantica+champa\U00f1a+acomodaci\U00f3n en cama doble";
    descuento = 61;
    "id_cupon" = 536;
    "id_sucursal" = 50;
    lat = "4.669106";
    lon = "-74.043949";
    premium = 1;
    rutaimagen = "ruta/imagen/7";
    tipooferta = "% Descuento";
    titulo = "Lavado de autos Splash";
    zona = 1;
},
    {
    ancla = "<null>";
    categoria = 3;
    descripcion = "Durante el mes de septiembre lleva uno de nuestros colchones Elegance por tan solo $429.000. Precio normal: $858.000. Te lo llevamos hasta la puerta de tu casa \U00a1y no te cuesta m\U00e1s!";
    descuento = 51;
    "id_cupon" = 537;
    "id_sucursal" = 54;
    lat = "4.655775";
    lon = "-74.099317";
    premium = 1;
    rutaimagen = "ruta/imagen/11";
    tipooferta = "% Descuento";
    titulo = "Lavado de autos Splash";
    zona = 1;
},
    {
    ancla = "<null>";
    categoria = 4;
    descripcion = "$240.0000 en ves de $480.000 por  3 dias y 4 noche en el Hotel Hilton de Bogot\U00e1 en acomodaci\U00f3n doble";
    descuento = 51;
    "id_cupon" = 535;
    "id_sucursal" = 45;
    lat = "4.63323";
    lon = "-74.144474";
    premium = 1;
    rutaimagen = "ruta/imagen/2";
    tipooferta = "% Descuento";
    titulo = "Lavado de autos Splash";
    zona = 1;
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do if the keys are identical?

Comment: can you please elaborate you question...about comparing and saving values.

Comment: I want to save identical values in NSMutableArray, to create cluster annotations using kingpin

Comment: So if there is two dictionaries that have the same "id_sucursal" you want them both in the array or just one of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want unique NSDictionary objects from the array, then I suggest you use NSSet instead of NSArray.

This will help you to add only unique objects to the NSSet. It is very easy to use and the below link is something you want because I resolved such a case using NSMutableSet :

[NSSet Tutorial](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/nsset.html)

Answer (score 0):

After you change JSON to Objective C structures, for example using:

```
NSArray *mainArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

You can iterate like that:

```
NSMutableArray* duplicates = [NSMutableArray array]; //keeping duplicated entries
NSMutableArray* uniques = [NSMutableArray array]; //to keep track on which ids where visited

for (NSDictionary* dict in mainArray)
{
    NSNumber* id_sucursal = [dict objectForKey:@"id_sucursal"]; //get id of current element
    BOOL isDuplicated = NO;

    for (NSNumber* uniqueId in uniques) //for all visited ids
    {
        if([id_sucursal isEqualToNumber:uniqueId]) //if same id was already found before
        {
            isDuplicated = YES;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(isDuplicated)
    {
         [duplicates addObject:dict]; //add element to duplicated list
    }
    else 
    { 
         [uniques addObject:id_sucursal]; //add id to visited ids 
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very inefficient.  At the very least you should use an NSSet to check for duplicates.

Comment: Agree - but I don't want to overcomplicate an answer - he will get NSArray from JSON - so I answered in most straight away version I could come up with. PLease feel free to change it to NSSet and post your answer. I bet my code make less loops trhough all objects than you're gonna do with your NSSet approach :D

Comment: It's not about the number of loops.  Finding an item in a set is O(log(n)), finding it in an array is O(n).  Not only that, implementing your own search lacks readability

Comment: I want to know is group all identical key values i. e. id_sucursal=45 to create a annotations cluster